# Find array with a specific data string and return another data string it has

Tags: php, json

I have this JSON(Cant change it)
every array in bbData contains["Username","ID","Age"]

```
{"bbData":[
 ["Peter","/id/5423","42.4"],
 ["Bob","/id/5355","32.1"],
 ["Dolan","/id/5113","22.6"]
]]}
```

I know an id for a user, let's say "/id/5423".
How can i then make PHP find the array with that id and return the age data which lays in the same array?

Comment: you need to decode it with json_decode and then you can check by array_values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP >= 5.5.0

```
$data = json_decode($myJsonString);
$searchId = "/id/5355";

$key = array_search($searchId, array_column($data->bbData, 1));
if ($key === false) {
    $found = $searchId, ' not found';
} else {
    $found = $data->bbData[$key];
}
var_dump($found);
```

**EDIT**

For earlier versions of PHP, replace

```
$key = array_search($searchId, array_column($data->bbData, 1));
```

with

```
$key = array_search(
    $searchId, 
    array_map(
        function($value) {
            return $value[1];
        },
        $data->bbData
    )
);
```

Comment: I dont have the version. Is there any similar way to do it in an earlier version?

Comment: Ok it seems to work. But let's say i only want to search a part of the id. So i only got "355" but the id string is "/id/6355". So it searches for a id value that just contains "355" and are not equal to. You understand?

Answer (score 0):

Decode the array into PHP first -

```
$users = json_decode($jsonString,true);
```

Then (there will be a better way of doing this with array_search), but this will suffice for you -

```
$knownUserId = 123;
$userDetails = false;

foreach($users AS $user) {
    if($user[1] == '/id/'.$knownUserId) {
        $userDetails = $user;
        break;
    }
}
```

You now have the user details in `$userDetails`

Comment: This would not suit my need, because the json file is very big. Forgot to mention it. This would not be good because i would need to search every single array. Is there any faster way?

Comment: How big is very big? You might be surprised at how quickly PHP can iterate through a foreach loop